# Finding array keys between two key values

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array where the keys are timestamps, and the values are ids.

For example:

```
[11111111] => 11

[12345678] => 21

[12345679] => 4

[12345688] => 2

[22222222] => 1
```

If I had two timestamps, like 12345677 and 12345689 for example, what would be the most effective way of finding the items that have keys between those two values?  For the example the items returned would be 21, 4, and 2, but I am working with a large data set (200000 plus items) so it will have to be efficient.

Comment: If the data comes from a database, then you're best handling the query there; otherwise, where does your data come from?

Comment: Keys are in order, but gaps are definitely there.  As in the example.

Comment: Seems the approach I'm using may be poor.  Basically I have a large number of start and end dates, and I need to retrieve items from a large table with either start dates between those two dates, or end dates between those two dates (overlapping).  The table is indexed on start and end dates, but it is still taking two long.  I'm trying to devise a way to store all the items in memory in such a way that I can rapidly retrieve ids based on whether the start or end date falls in a certain range.

Comment: I now read this comment. If you have this in your database, DONT use a php array. Those are VERY slow. MySQL is a better friend if you need to find those values fast. Something like `SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE timeColumn BETWEEN $start AND $stop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getMiddlePart($array, $startTime, $tillTime){
    $returnvalues = array();
    asort( $array ); // sort the array (if needed, otherwise remove this)

    // loop forward through the array until proper time is found
    while( key(current($array)) < $startTime){ next($array); } 

    // check if we didnt end at the last one:
    if( key(current($array)) !== key( end($array)){
        // while the $tilltime isnt exeded, store in array:
        while( key(next($array))<= $tillTime){
            $returnvalues[] = current($array); // store current value
        }
    }

    // return array. Can be length===0
    return $returnvalues;
}
```

This function works by changing the pointer of the array with `next()` untill a time is found which is greater that $startTime.

While writing this I notice the first pointer is wrong, ill correct that in my next edit

*I'm looking for a method to improve moving the pointer to the proper location, so if anyone has a nice suggestion, just leave in comments :)

---

To simply explain a pointer:
A pointer is a piece of information in the code which remembers where in the array you are. If you dont do anything with an array, the pointer is at the first item.  If you loop through it with a `foreach()`, it sets the pointer to the next value, thats why you can use the same variable names in that loop.

```
$array[1] = 'aaa';
$array[2] = 'bbb';
$array[3] = 'ccc';
$array[4] = 'ddd';
$array[5] = 'eee';

echo current($array); // will output: aaa

next(array); // move pointer to the next item
echo current($array); // will now output: bbb

end(array); // set to last item
echo current($array); // will now output: eee

reset(array); // reset, will go back to first item:
echo current($array); // will now output: aaa
```

---

This is not the fastest method for very large datasets, you count do something like this:

```
$curKey = key( current($array) ); // get first key
$arrLength = count($array); 
$offsetLarge = $arrLength * 0.1;  // 10% keys per step
$offsetSmall = $arrLength * 0.05; //  5% keys per step

while( $array[$curKey ] < $startTime ){
    $curKey += $offsetLarge; // INcrease untill limit is met
}
// we are now roughly above it
while( $array[$curKey ] > $startTime ){
    $curKey -= $offsetSmall; // DEcrease untill limit is met
}

//if you want to proceed in smaller steps:
$offsetLarge *= 0.1; // 1% keys per loop
$offsetSmall *= 0.1; // 1% keys per loop
while( $array[$curKey ] < $startTime ){
    $curKey += $offsetLarge; // INcrease untill limit is met
}
// we are now roughly above it
while( $array[$curKey ] > $startTime ){
    $curKey -= $offsetSmall; // DEcrease untill limit is met
}
// At this point you are very close ($curKey) should be just below it and can loop up till found value.
```

Comment: That requires the array to be sorted.  Plus the start key and lastkey might not actually be in the array.  They are just bounding time stamp values.

Comment: The start key and end key will rarely even exist.  I am just trying to find the keys that do exist between those two values.

Comment: @Vulcronos: added a sort if needed, doing that when not needed is a waste of time, so I added comment about optional

Comment: @user1599246: I've changed the code, the keys no longer need to exist, it just loops until a greater time is found

Comment: K lemme set up a test implementation with my dataset and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Why the downvote? I dont mind a downvote, but I'd like to know why.  @user1599246: Sure. Might be the pointer is off by one to your likings, you might want to play with `>=` instead of `=`

Comment: I got a working version of this but it doesn't scale for large sets of data well enough.  Back to the drawing board. I'm gonna accept this answer because it's the closest answer to my question put forward, and did work for smaller data sets.

Comment: You could make something that starts at 50%, if that is too big, go to 25%, if thats to small 37.5% untill you find the right start. that would save allot of loop-time

Comment: I´ve added some theoretical code which might give you an idea what you can do. That should be faster.